# How to annotate a field with information from a specific manytomany entity?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, orm

I have 2 models and a manytomany relationship between then, Property and Owners, they are pretty much the following:

```py
class Property(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    owners = models.ManyToManyField('Owner', through='PropertyOwner')
    ...

class Owner(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("Owner's name", max_length=50)
    ...

class PropertyOwner(models.Model):
    property = models.ForeignKey('Property', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    owner = models.ForeignKey('Owner', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    current = models.BooleanField()
```

How can I annotate a new field in my `Property.objects.all()` queryset with the current owner's id. (maybe using `.first()`)

Comment: I assume your software enforces that there is only one `current=True` per owner?

Comment: Likely your `owner = ...` foreign key should refer to the `Owner`, not the `Property`?

Comment: Oh, my bad. I fixed it. Exactly, there's only one with the current field True

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to do this is by making a property that will make a query (per `Property`) to obtain the current owner. This thus looks like:

```
class Property(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    owners = models.ManyToManyField('Owner', through='PropertyOwner')

    @property
    def current_owner(self):
        return self.owners.filter(propertyowner__current=True).first()
```

If we however load a lot of `Property`s, and we need to find the current owner for each `Property`, this will result in a lot of queries.

An alternative might be to make a query to obtain the `Property`s with the primary key of the current owner, then load all these owners, and finally assigning these owners to the `Property` objects. This thus looks like:

We can annotate the `QuerySet` with the primary key of the current owner, and then fetch these in bulk and implement the JOIN logic in Django:

```
from operator import attrgetter

properties = list(Property.objects.filter(
    propertyowner__current=True
).annotate(
    current_owner_id=F('owners__pk')
))

owners = set(map(attrgetter('current_owner_id'), properties))
owners = {
    owner.pk: owner
    for owner in Owner.objects.filter(pk__in=owners)
}

for property in properties:
    property.current_owner = owners.get(property.current_owner_id)
```

After this code fragment, `properties` is a list of `Property` objects that have an extra attribute: `.current_owner` which is an `Owner` object for the person currently owning that `Property`.